# SVG stroke-width problems on Retina

Tags: javascript, css, macos, svg

I have an svg lines:

```
<path class="nav-polyline side" data-button="left" d="M28,334.29998779296875,28,28,996,28,996,370" style="stroke-dashoffset: 1658px; stroke-dasharray: 1708px; stroke-width: 1px; transform: none;" data-l="1708" data-r="1663"></path>
```

The problem is it's width is not 1px on retina (tested on 27' iMac) they're 2px width on iMac, on iPad it look ok. What shall I do to set their width to 1px even on iMac?

Just on Safari

[Live demo](http://dev.openform.pl/news)

This is lanes on top/right/bottom/left side of screen. When you press for example top element you're going to other view. Some kind of subsite, just on those subsites this problem exists.

Comment: Can you reproduce the problem in plunker / snippet?

Comment: I insert link to a live demo, there is a problem :c

Comment: On what UA? Chrome, Firefox, Safari, all of the above?

Comment: Just safari, sorry

Comment: raise a [webkit](https://bugs.webkit.org/) bug then.

Comment: try not using units (i.e. lose the `px`) and see if that makes a difference. I have not had issues like that on retina ... but I don't use unit on svgs ;)